# How to prevent Karma from removing a file?

Tags: karma-runner

Karma works perfect with Notepad++. When I use Visual Studio as my text editor it removes the file it is supposed to watch after I save the file. This is the output from Karma showing the error:

[image]

[This](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/issues/199) is the ticket that is being presented as the solution but it doesn't fix anything.

Is there any way to setup the config file so that it still uses autoWatch (tests on every save) but doesn't remove the file if I use Visual Studio?

I've tried

- running the command prompt as admin
- setting autoWatchBatchDelay, in the config file, to a large number (2500)

This is my current config file:

```
module.exports = function (config) {
    config.set({

        files: [
            'e2e.js'
        ],

        autoWatch: true,

        browsers: ['IE', 'Chrome'],

        frameworks: ['jasmine'],

        autoWatch: true,

        plugins: [
                'karma-ie-launcher',
                'karma-chrome-launcher',
                'karma-jasmine'
        ]
    });
}
```

Answer (score 8):

The only way that I have made this work is by watching a folder instead of a file.

In `files`, watch `'*.js'` instead of `'e2e.js'`.

Comment: A note for `gulp-karma` users: this workaround won't help you if you pass the files array to `gulp.src()` instead of specifying them in `karma.config`. So, move them to `karma.config` and use a fake path in `gulp.config` like this: `gulp.src('./fakepath').pipe(karma) ...`

Comment: This worked for me. I had `files: ['stuff.js', 'stuff_test.js'],` and by changing it to `files: ['stuff*.js'],` it all begun to work.